# Loading URL without webview

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

How can I load a URL without using WebView because my class has not a visual display it's just .java file and dont have .xml file in res/layout folder

I just want to load URL, not displaying or something. I will use it for sending information like that.

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    //Code here
    //Load("mywebsite.com/register.php?token="+token)
}
```

I tried searching but found nothing to solve this issue.

Thank u :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request)

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```